# Create a SQL Format File from a .txt for a bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

I have a question and I would like to know if it is possible. I am running SQL Server 2008. I have a .txt file that is generated from an outside system. This .txt file has multiple delimiters, so I instantly thought of using the bcp utility to generate a format file for this .txt ,in order to insert into a temp table with a bulk insert. However, I am unsure if I can use the bcp utility on a text file to generate the .fmt that would be used in tandem with the bulk insert command to preform the data transfer.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or any other way that I can use multiple row terminators inside of a bulk insert command?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Format Files were indeed the way to go. I ended up creating one by hand without using the BCP utility and referenced the file in the bulk insert and it works like a charm